# Linear interpolation library with php

Tags: php, interpolation

I need to interpolate points with php, do you know any library for that? A traditional search did not allow me to find any that good results.

I have a table with values in columns x and y.

```
X          Y
10       676
20       894
30      1100
40      1200
50      1000
```

I was wondering if there is a function that can help with linear interpolation.  For example, I want the interpolated value of Y that corresponds to X=35.

Thanks

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic*

Comment: You're most likely going to have to implement this on your own or switch to a language that does have libraries that do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's simple math - no need to use any library at all.

If you want the `Y` value of `X`, you have to find the greatest value smaller than `X` (`x0`) and the lowest value greater than `X` (`x1`).
If this two values are equal, you don't have to do anything and just return the `Y` value in your table.

Otherwise, take the two corresponding `Y` values (`y0` and `y1`) and do a interpolation with them.

```
d = (x - x0) / (x1 - x0) // value in the range of [0; 1]
y = y0 * (1 - d) + y1 * d // your interpolated value
```

in your case of `x = 35` => `x0 = 30`, `x1 = 40`

```
d = (35 - 30) / (40 - 30) // 0.5
y = 1100 * (1 - 0.5) + 1200 * 0.5 // 1150
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `d` variable is? Most articles I have read on linear interpolation use the following formula which seems different to yours but returns the same result: `y = y0 + (x - x0) * ((y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0))`

Comment: Imagine you walk from point 1 (`x0`) to point 2 (`x1`) and want to know, how far you already come. If you are still at the starting point, `d` is obviously `0`. After the half distance, d becomes `0.5` and if you finally reacht `x1`, `d` is `1`. The second line is than simply the inverse step - but in the other number range.

Comment: @Philipp thanks for your very simple explanation, could you also extrapolate the X = 60? Thanks! :>

Comment: For 60 I would extrapolate with x0=40, X1=50 which results in d=2 and a value of 800